# Elliptic curve in finite field, which solution to choose?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, elliptic-equations

This is the elliptic curve I'm working with in the finite field of mod 37:

$$
y^2 = x^3 - 5x + 8
$$
While trying to generate the set of points in it I noticed that, for $x = 5$,

$$
y^2 = 5^3 - 5\times 5 + 8 \text{ mod 37} = 34 \text{ mod 37}
$$

Now there are two numbers that satisfies the above equation, namely, $16$ and $21$. Because, 
$$
16^2  = 21^2 = 34 \text{ mod 37}
$$

Which value should I choose for the elliptic curve? Would either be good or is there any other rules in this case? TIA.

Comment: They are both valid points on the elliptic curve. In fact, because the exponent of $y^2$ is even, the point $(x,y)$ is on the curve whenever $(x,-y)$ is. Of course, modular arithmetic implies that automatically $-y=37-y$. Observe that $21=37-16=-16$ in the field $\Bbb{F}_{37}$.

Comment: i see... thanks!